# Why am I not getting same result using while and until in ruby?

Tags: ruby, logic, boolean-logic

Ok, I'm using Ruby 2.26 on windows x64.
The thing is, I'm really just new at learning how to code, so I'm not sure wether this is truly a bug or it's simply my mistakes somewhere, because the bug is VERY VERY SIMPLE it's kinda dumb(?) @_@

The 'while' and 'until' operator.

As far as I know,

```
action = gets.chomp
until action == "a" || action == "b"
  puts "Answer a or b"
  action = gets.chomp
end

puts "The answer: " + action
```

and

```
action = gets.chomp
while action != "a" || action != "b"
  puts "Answer a or b"
  action = gets.chomp
end

puts "The answer: " + action
```

should result in the same thing. But using the 'while' operator here, get me infinite loop even if I'm putting "a" or "b" on user input on the powershell.
Anyone can tell me why this is? Or is this truly a bug? (which is a shame since a while and until operator should be a very basic logic operator right?)

Comment: That is not a ruby specific issue. I would suggest you to read the [Boolean algebra operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

The opposite of

```
action == "a" || action == "b"
```

is

```
action != "a" && action != "b"
```

See [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

## Your code

```
action != "a" || action != "b"
```

is always `true` :

- if `action` is `"a"`, it is `false || true`, which is `true`
- if `action` is `"b"`, it is `true || false`, which is `true`
- if `action` is neither, it is `true || true`, which is `true`

So your loop really is `while true`.

Note : There surely are bugs in Ruby, and some of them might be trivially simple. It doesn't mean that anything you don't understand is a bug, though. ;)

## Language and boolean logic

It isn't always easy to extract boolean logic from sentences :

"You like cats **and** dogs"

You would like to know if you like an `animal`. To do so, you need to check if `animal` is a dog **or** a cat.

If you check that `animal` is a dog **and** a cat, you surely won't like the animal!

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right! 
I though the reading in English was simply
"While action is not a OR action is not b". So the logic escapes me here.
Please forgive my ignorance :D Thank you very much for clearing this up. Hope I can be a great coder someday~